# Using QgsNewVectorLayerDialog

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt

I am using `QgsNewVectorLayerDialog` for taking user input for creating a new shapefile. When the user clicks OK I am reading the inputs selected by the user using the following code.

```
dlg = QgsNewVectorFileDialog()
result = dlg.exec_()
if result == 1:
   crs = dlg.selectedCrsI()
   type = dlg.selectedType()
   attributes = []
   dlg.attributes(attributes)
```

All other parameters are coming fine. However attributes is returning an empty list.
`QgsNewVectorLayerDialog.attributes()` shows that it needs an list of tuple of QString-QString.
Whether I am passing correctly or not.

Comment: It sounds like a bug. I suggest you to report it at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues. See http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html#bugs-features-and-issues for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is really a bug as Carrillo said.

But as a workaround, I implemented my own class `OwnVectorLayerDialog` inheriting `QgsNewVectorLayerDialog` and override the `attributes()` function. Therefore, I oriented on original c++ function from API: http://qgis.org/api/qgsnewvectorlayerdialog_8cpp_source.html#l00192

The only hack was to find `QTreeWidget` in dialog children - found a QGroupbox at index 9 and the tree at index 1 within that groupbox (maybe you have to find it yourself, if you are using other version, where indices might have changed)

My code looks like this:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsNewVectorLayerDialog
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTreeWidgetItemIterator


class OwnVectorLayerDialog(QgsNewVectorLayerDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=Qt.Window):
        super(OwnVectorLayerDialog, self).__init__(parent, flags)

    def attributes(self, att_list):
        # Find QTreeWidget:
        tree = self.children()[9].children()[1]

        # Iterate over items:
        it = QTreeWidgetItemIterator(tree)
        while it.value() is not None:
            item = it.value()
            item_type = "{0};{1};{2}".format(
                item.text(1), item.text(2), item.text(3))
            att_list.append((item.text(0), item_type))
            it += 1

dlg = OwnVectorLayerDialog()
result = dlg.exec_()
if result == 1:
    crs = dlg.selectedCrsId()
    types = dlg.selectedType()
    attributes = []
    dlg.attributes(attributes)

    print(crs)
    print(types)
    print(attributes)
```

And gives me output like this (for `id` field and added field `new_field`):

```
3452
1
[(u'id', 'Integer;10;'), (u'new_field', 'Real;10;3')]
```

Hope you can adapt and use my workaround!

Comment: Instead of overriding the `attributes()` function you could write your own function returning the fields as you want it, of course...